# How does decisive supporting cause (upanissaya paccaya) work? (and some related questions)

Tags: theravada, karma, pali-canon, nirvana, parami

According to **Theravada** Buddhism:

1.How does Decisive Supporting Cause (Upanissaya Paccaya) work?  For example, when Venerable arahant Anuruddha asked Sangha what to do to attain divine-eye in Lord Padumuttara Buddha's dispensation, why did Sangha tell him to offer light to Buddha's stupa instead of practising kasina meditation? Did that offering become a supporting cause for him to attain divine eye? If yes, how? Aren't sensual wholesome kamma and fine-material (rupavacara) kamma different and unrelated?

2.Similarly, Venerable arahant Panchadeepadaika (Apadana pali - Bhikkuni apadana, 15th apadana) says that she became proficient in samadhi and dibba-caccu abhinna (divine-eye) as a result of offering 5 lamps to Lord Padumuttara Buddha's bodhi tree. She must not have practised kasina because she was born in the second deva realm in the subsequent life. How did this happen? Does the results of light-offering kamma give you the ability (such as a clear mind) to succeed in kasina meditation therefore attain samadhi and abhinna?

3.Also, Venerable arahant Pilindawachcha  (Apadana pali - Bhikku apadana, 391st apadana) says that he obtained a great wisdom power as a result of offering knives, needles, razors and fragrance to Lord Padumuttara Buddha and Sangha. Can you please explain how offering can increase wisdom through Upanissaya Paccaya? I thought wisdom can only be developed through meditation.

4.I think my samadhi and wisdom faculty, out of five faculties, are very weak. If I made an offering to Buddha (such as light, fragrance) and Sangha and make a wish that in future lives, I get the ability to attain all 8 jhanas and abhinna quickly in one sitting and to develop vipassana meditation quickly and deeply, would such a wish become true? Can that kamma develop my five faculties so that I become proficient in meditation in future lives and attain nirvana?

Thank you. May the Triple Gem Bless you all!

Comment: Paccaya, origination, doesn't need to arising. It could be arose or will arise or never arise (imagination). Our parent don't need to be alive, living, when we recall to them (arammana-upanissaya-paccaya).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work that way around. Does one know whether not having given light on good place before? Or what else required? Paramis are technical complete at once, if going forth in this Sasana. So better to seek for Upanissaya toward the good Sangha, as present most useful Nissaya-paccaya and gives up what ever still carried with.

(one wouldn't be able to take this, if there had been no upanissaya-paccaya before, no strong relation cause.)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to refer to [Upanisasutta](https://suttacentral.net/sn12.23/en/sujato?layout=plain&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=false&script=latin)

If you can see that wishing for a future life itself as craving, caused by ignorance and the delusion, you would abandon it. If you have Faith in the Buddha, then your goal should be Nibbana. That is, to end Rebirth.

If your goal becomes Nibbana instead, then you can start practicing (i.e. developing) the [Noble Eight Fold Path](https://suttacentral.net/mn117/en/sujato?layout=plain&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=false&script=latin) and Five Powers and Five Faculties will develop as a result of that.

As a starting point you can refer to this meditation on the [Noble Eightfold path](https://visuddhimagga.info/download.php?file=https://anaalaya.blob.core.windows.net/dhamma2019/M_E_Eightfoldpath_13_07_2019.mp4) which is the first out of a 15 meditation program, and the last one is [Suka patipada Khippabhinna -pleasant means and quick realization](https://visuddhimagga.info/download.php?file=https://anaalaya.blob.core.windows.net/dhamma2019/M_E_SukaPatipadhaKhippabhinna_16_07_2019.mp4).